# How to make a href link to a name AND not bring it to the top of site

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

here's what I'm using

```
<h1>Red to Violet</h1>
<a href="#one">first</a> .
<a href="#two">second</a> .

<div id="section">
<div class="innersections">
<a name="one"></a>

(text)

</div> <hr> 
<div class="innersections">
<a name="two"></a>
(text)

</div></div>
```

---

I want it so that when I click a link, it doesn't take the page up and I can't see the title 'red to violet' but I can see the second 'innersections' if I clicked 'second'.
note; I can only use css/html codes.

Comment: Can't without JavaScript. I'm not sure I understand the request, though.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't want anchor based navigation to work the way it should?

Comment: Agree. You need JavaScript to implement this functionality.
Could you describe the required functionality more detailed? Should it be like tabs functionality?

Comment: When I click link, I want the h1 to still show at the top of the page. is there a way to make javascript work on a page that only has for css/html?

Comment: Yes, just include JavaScript to your page

Comment: @iran tahirkheli , would I need anything special in css for it to work?

Comment: oh ok, I think I understand! Thanks! Gonna head to class now.

Comment: @IsabelNava : No you dont need to do anything with css.

Comment: What's the point of those links, then? What *should* happen when you click one of them? If you don't want anything to happen, just remove the href. :)

Comment: The second innersections should be viewed instead of the first, I don't really want the whole page to move.

Answer (score 1):

Use id with element you want to navigate to.

```
<h1>Red to Violet</h1>
<a href="#one">first</a> .
<a href="#two">second</a> .

<div id="section">
<div class="innersections">
<a id="one" name="one"></a>

(text)

</div> <hr> 
<div class="innersections">
<a id="two" name="two"></a>
(text)

</div></div>
```

Comment: id also will scroll to the element so it's not the solution

Comment: So what is the goal if you don't want to scrol to the element. @Kont

Comment: I also want to know. Let's wait for TS's comment. @Irfan TahirKheli

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat the h1 header to remain at the top, you can use `position:fixed;top:0`.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZjdN/) that illustrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/VZjdN/ (I've made some small changes to your HTML. If you don't want to use an HTML5 `header` tag, you can use a `div`.)

The full CSS is:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.innersections {
    padding-top: 5em;
}
```

And the modified mark-up:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Red to Violet</h1>
        <a href="#one">first</a>. <a href="#two">second</a>.
    </header>

    <div id="section"> 
        <a name="one"></a>
        <div class="innersections" style="padding-top:6em">
             <h2>Inner 1</h2>
            <div style="height:800px"></div>  <!-- filler -->
        </div>
        <hr> 

        <a name="two"></a>
        <div class="innersections" style="padding-top:4em">
             <h2>Inner 2</h2>
            <div style="height:800px"></div> <!-- filler -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I came up with this solution too, but I didn't posted because the fixed header is not taken in account by the scroll navigation. This is a fix http://jsfiddle.net/GPRVX/ .... here are several ways to solve it http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo

Comment: I already have other divs (navigation) being set to fixed/top:0px

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

http://jsfiddle.net/GPRVX/

```
.section {
    margin-top: 8em;
}
.fix {
    height: 7em;
    top:0; left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: white;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
.innersections {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.section a:before {
    display:block; 
    content:""; 
    height:8em; 
    margin:-8em 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: it's just that I have more content before that, do you think I should post the WHOLE code? because it's pretty long...

Comment: I think I'll use this and just separate the content above red to violet. (putting it next to it in another div instead.) thanks~